# CMake 2.8 does in-source-builds although I ask for out-of-source. Why?

Tags: cmake

I call CMake 2.8 from an empty bin directory to do an out-of-source build:

```
> make ../svn/trunk/projekt/CMakeList.txt
```

but instead of generating the makefiles in place, CMake puts them into the source tree.

The CMake FAQ says that in this case you should look for `CMakeCache.txt` files in the source tree that trigger in-source-builds, but there are none.

Explicitly setting the binary directory doesn't work neither:

```
> make -DCMAKE_BINARY_DIR=`pwd` ../svn/trunk/projekt/CMakeList.txt
```

Any ideas what I can try else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean `cmake ../svn/trunk/projekt/CMakeList.txt` rather than `make ...`? That's the wrong way to do it. You need to specify the path to the top level of the CMake project not the CMakeLists.txt file itself, so after having removed the CMakeCache.txt files you should run:

```
cmake ../svn/trunk/projekt
```

Comment: No problem. I had to test this out as I couldn't quite believe doing it this way actually caused such strange behavior!